# Pizza combinations possible given our options

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I own a pizza shop and have tried to come up with the different possibilities of pizza options available given our toppings for any given pizza.  We have 4 crust options thin, regular, thick,gluten free we then have six (6) sauces plus no sauce and can be split 1/2 and 1/2, we have three cheese options, plus no cheese and can be split 1/2 and 1/2, 9 meat options 1/2 and 1/2, 9 vegetable options 1/2 and 1/2, 2 fruit options 1/2 and 1/2, 4 fish options 1/2 and 1/2, 4 seasoning options for the crust 1/2 and 1/2.  We also allow for these options to be used on 1/2 of any pizza excluding the 3 crust options for the crust must be the same for the complete pizza no matter what toppings are placed on it.  I am trying to figure out a baseline of just who many combinations we offer of pizza from our menu.  Thank you

Comment: Are there any other limitations in terms of what can be combined? Can I choose all 6 sauces or only 1? Can I put a sauce on half of the pizza? Can no sauce be used?

Comment: pretend you are building a pizza step by step and at each step ask yourself how many options you have for that step and multiply that number by the answer to the previous step

Comment: Can you have a split 1/2 and 1/2 from sauce 1 and sauce 2 on half of a pizza, and another split 1/2 and 1/2 from sauce 3 and sauce 4 on the other half of the pizza?

Comment: There are infinitely many ways to split a circular pizza into $2$ halves. So you can, for example, split the cheese into $2$ halves and split the meat into $2$ **other** halves. If you allow a different split for each category, then you have infinitely many pizza combinations. So we are forced to assume that you allow only a single split.

Comment: Can the gluten-free crust option be prepared in thick, thin and regular?

Answer (score 0):

***Total Pizzas (Bold Lines are What I've Assumed): 3 sextillion, 615 quintillion, 561 quadrillion, 838 trillion, 447 billion, 72 million, 116 thousand, 736***

Far less than the number of stars in the universe.

Multiply together the number of options in the selected lines below to get these total combinations. For lines with (each half) multiply the number twice.

**Crust Options if gluten-free thickness cannot be specified: 4**

Crust Options if gluten-free thickness can be specified: 8

**Sauce Options if at most 1 Permitted per half (Each Half): $7$**

Sauce Options if any number Permitted Per half (Each Half): $2^7=128$

Cheese Options if at most 1 permitted per half (Each Half): $4$

**Cheese Options if More than 1 Allowed (Each Half): $2^4=16$**

**Topping + Seasoning Options assuming any number allowed (Each Half):
$2^{(9+9+2+4+4)}=2^{28}=268435456$**